# How can I change the groupby column to find the first row that meets the conditions of a mask if the initial groupby failed to find it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

This is my DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'main': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y'],
        'sub': ['c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'g', 'g', 'g'],
        'num_1': [10, 9, 80, 80, 99, 101, 110, 222, 90, 1, 7, 10, 2, 10, 95, 10],
        'num_2': [99, 99, 99, 102, 102, 209, 209, 209, 209, 100, 100, 100, 100, 90, 90, 90]
    }
)
```

And This is my expected output. I want to add column `result`:

```
   main sub  num_1  num_2  result
0     x   c     10     99     101
1     x   c      9     99     101
2     x   c     80     99     101
3     x   d     80    102     110
4     x   d     99    102     110
5     x   e    101    209     222
6     x   e    110    209     222
7     x   e    222    209     222
8     x   e     90    209     222
9     y   f      1    100     NaN
10    y   f      7    100     NaN
11    y   f     10    100     NaN
12    y   f      2    100     NaN
13    y   g     10     90      95
14    y   g     95     90      95
15    y   g     10     90      95
```

The mask is:

```
mask = (df.num_1 > df.num_2)
```

The process starts like this:

**a)** The `groupby` column is `sub`

**b)** Finding the first row that meets the condition of the mask for each group.

**c)** Put the value of `num_1` in the `result`

If there are no rows that meets the condition of the mask, then the `groupby` column is changed to `main` to find the first row of `mask`. There is condition for this phase:

The previous `subs` should not be considered when using `main` as the `groupby` column.

An example of the above steps for group `d` in the `sub` column:

a) `sub` is the `groupby` column.

b) There are no rows in the `d` group that `df.num_1 > df.num_2`

So now for group `d`, its `main` group is searched. However group `c` is also in this `main` group. Since it is before group `d`, group `c` should not count for this step.

In this image I have shown where those values come from:

[image]

And this is my attempt. It partially solves the issue for some groups but not all of them:

```
def step_a(g):
    mask = (g.num_1 > g.num_2)

    g.loc[mask.cumsum().eq(1) & mask, 'result'] = g.num_1
    g['result'] = g.result.ffill().bfill()
    return g

a = df.groupby('sub').apply(step_a)
```

Comment: What should be the output if 99 and 102 where inverted in num2?

Comment: @mozway df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'main': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y'],
        'sub': ['d', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'g', 'g', 'g'],
        'num_1': [10, 9, 80, 80, 99, 101, 110, 222, 90, 1, 7, 10, 2, 10, 95, 10],
        'num_2': [102, 102, 99, 99, 99, 209, 209, 209, 209, 100, 100, 100, 100, 90, 90, 90]
    }
)

Comment: @mozway you mean this dataframe?

Comment: Indeed that one.

Comment: @mozway nothing changes. `result` is same

Comment: @mozway   
main sub  num_1  num_2   result
0     x   d     10    102   110
1     x   d      9    102   110
2     x   c     80     99   101 
3     x   c     80     99   101
4     x   c     99     99   101

Comment: I don't get your last comment without proper formatting

Comment: @mozway for group `d` result is 110 and for group `c` result is 101 still.

Comment: Then why isn't 10 the output of f?

Comment: @mozway because 10 < 100 :)

Comment: But 101 < 102, thus my original question -> "*for group c result is 101 still.*"

Comment: @mozway let me rephrase the issue. first of all `num_2` in a single group is always same. For example for group f `num_2`  is 100 throughout the whole group. I want to find the first row that `num_1 > num_2`. First we search the red lines boundry. If it is not found, we search themain boundry from where the `sub ` ends. For group `f` there are no rows that `num_1 > num_2` and in its `main` boundry there is also no rows. For the dataframe in the comments for group `c` there are no rows in the red line boundry so then we search the main boundry. the first row that is greater than 99 is 101.

Comment: So back to my first question, would 101/110 be swapped in the result for the alternative input?

Comment: @mozway If your dataframe is the df that i have posted in the comments, the solution that has been posted below gives me the exact result that I want.

Comment: @mozway Maybe I cannot put together the correct words :)

Comment: @mozway I'm very excited if you got an elegant solution for this. You are just on another level, you know :)

Comment: IIUC, then the values in the result are swapped, let me write a potential solution ;)

Comment: @mozway  I cant wait :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) broadcasting to form a mask per "main" and use this to find the first num1>num2 while considering only the next groups:

```
def find(g):
    # get sub as 0,1,2…
    sub = pd.factorize(g['sub'])[0]
    # convert inputs to numpy
    n1 = g['num_1'].to_numpy()
    n2 = g.loc[~g['sub'].duplicated(), 'num_2'].to_numpy()
    # form mask
    # (n1[:, None] > n2) -> num_1 > num_2
    # (sub[:, None] >= np.arange(len(n2))) -> exclude previous groups
    m = (n1[:, None] > n2) & (sub[:, None] >= np.arange(len(n2)))
    # find first True per column
    return pd.Series(np.where(m.any(0), n1[m.argmax(0)], np.nan)[sub],
                     index=g.index)


df['result'] = df.groupby('main', group_keys=False).apply(find)
```

*Note that you can easily tweak the masks to perform other logics (search in next n groups, exclude all previous groups except the immediate previous one, etc.).*

Outputs:

```
# example 1                               # example 2 (from comments)
   main sub  num_1  num_2  result            main sub  num_1  num_2  result
0     x   c     10     99   101.0         0     x   d     10    102   110.0
1     x   c      9     99   101.0         1     x   d      9    102   110.0
2     x   c     80     99   101.0         2     x   c     80     99   101.0
3     x   d     80    102   110.0         3     x   c     80     99   101.0
4     x   d     99    102   110.0         4     x   c     99     99   101.0
5     x   e    101    209   222.0         5     x   e    101    209   222.0
6     x   e    110    209   222.0         6     x   e    110    209   222.0
7     x   e    222    209   222.0         7     x   e    222    209   222.0
8     x   e     90    209   222.0         8     x   e     90    209   222.0
9     y   f      1    100     NaN         9     y   f      1    100     NaN
10    y   f      7    100     NaN         10    y   f      7    100     NaN
11    y   f     10    100     NaN         11    y   f     10    100     NaN
12    y   f      2    100     NaN         12    y   f      2    100     NaN
13    y   g     10     90    95.0         13    y   g     10     90    95.0
14    y   g     95     90    95.0         14    y   g     95     90    95.0
15    y   g     10     90    95.0         15    y   g     10     90    95.0
```

Intermediate masks `m`, here for the second example:

```
# main == 'x'
#          99    102    209
array([[False, False, False],  #  10
       [False, False, False],  #   9
       [False, False, False],  #  80
       [False, False, False],  #  80
       [False, False, False],  #  99
       [False,  True, False],  # 101
       [ True,  True, False],  # 110
       [ True,  True,  True],  # 222
       [False, False, False]]) #  90
# out:    110    101    222


# main == 'y'
#         100     90
array([[False, False],  #   1
       [False, False],  #   7
       [False, False],  #  10
       [False, False],  #   1
       [False, False],  #  10
       [False,  True],  #  95
       [False, False]]) #  90
# out:    NaN     95
```

Comment: Imagine there is another numerical column called `num_3` and If I change the mask to  `df.num_2.between(df.num_1, df.num_3)`,  What should be changed in this code? I tried these `c = g['num_3'].to_numpy()` and also this one `m = (a[:, None] < b) &  (a[:, None] > c) & (sub[:, None] >= np.arange(len(b)))`. But it does not work.
`

Comment: @x_Amir_x can you open a new question with the details?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78248551/10200497  everything is same. The mask changed though.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

define custom function

```
def get_result(d):
    cond = d['num_1'].gt(d['num_2'])
    if cond.sum() > 0:
        target = d['num_1'].where(cond).bfill().iloc[0]        
    else:
        df1 = df[df['main'].eq(d['main'].iloc[0])]
        s1 = df1['num_2'].where(df1['sub'].eq(d['sub'].iloc[0])).ffill()
        target = df1['num_1'].where(df1['num_1'].gt(s1)).bfill().iloc[0]

    return pd.Series(target, index=d.index)
```

make `result` column

```
df['result'] = df.groupby(['main', 'sub'], group_keys=False).apply(get_result)
```

df:

```
   main sub  num_1  num_2  result
0     x   c     10     99   101.0
1     x   c      9     99   101.0
2     x   c     80     99   101.0
3     x   d     80    102   110.0
4     x   d     99    102   110.0
5     x   e    101    209   222.0
6     x   e    110    209   222.0
7     x   e    222    209   222.0
8     x   e     90    209   222.0
9     y   f      1    100     NaN
10    y   f      7    100     NaN
11    y   f     10    100     NaN
12    y   f      2    100     NaN
13    y   g     10     90    95.0
14    y   g     95     90    95.0
15    y   g     10     90    95.0
```