# How can I change the groupby scope to find the first value that meets the conditions of a mask?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

This is an extension to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78246775/how-can-i-change-the-groupby-column-to-find-the-first-row-that-meets-the-condtio).

My DataFrame is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'main': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y'],
        'sub': ['c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'g', 'g', 'g'],
        'num_1': [97, 90, 105, 2100, 1000, 101, 110, 222, 90, 100, 99, 90, 2, 92, 95, 93],
        'num_2': [100, 100, 100, 102, 102, 209, 209, 209, 209, 100, 100, 100, 100, 90, 90, 90],
        'num_3': [99, 110, 110, 110, 110, 222, 222, 222, 222, 150, 101, 200, 5, 95, 95, 100],
        'label': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p']
    }
)
```

And this is the expected output. I want to create column `result`:

```
   main sub  num_1  num_2  num_3 label result
0     x   c     97    100     99     a      b
1     x   c     90    100    110     b      b
2     x   c    105    100    110     c      b
3     x   d   2100    102    110     d      f
4     x   d   1000    102    110     e      f
5     x   e    101    209    222     f      f
6     x   e    110    209    222     g      f
7     x   e    222    209    222     h      f
8     x   e     90    209    222     i      f
9     y   f    100    100    150     j      k
10    y   f     99    100    101     k      k
11    y   f     90    100    200     l      k
12    y   f      2    100      5     m      k
13    y   g     92     90     95     n    NaN
14    y   g     95     90     95     o    NaN
15    y   g     93     90    100     p    NaN
```

The mask is:

```
mask = (
    (df.num_1 < df.num_2) & 
    (df.num_2 < df.num_3)
)
```

The process starts like this:

**a)** The groupby column is `sub`

**b)** Finding the first row that meets the condition of the mask for each group.

**c)** Put the value of `label` in the result

If there are no rows that meets the condition of the mask, then the groupby column is changed to `main` to find the first row of mask. There is condition for this phase:

The previous `sub`s should not be considered when using `main` as the `groupby` column.

An example of the above steps for group `d` in the sub column:

**a)** `sub` is the groupby column.

**b)** There are no rows in the `d` group that `df.num_2` is between `df.num_1` and `df.num_3` (the condition of the `mask`)

So now for group `d`, its main group is searched. However group `c` is also in this main group. Since it is before group `d`, group `c` should not count for this step. So in `x` group the first row of the `mask` has `f` label (101 < 102 < 222).

One thing to note is that for each `sub` group `num_2` does not change throughout the group. For example for entire group `c` `num_2` is 100.

This is my attempt based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78246938/10200497) but it does not work:

```
def find(g):
    # get sub as 0,1,2…
    sub = pd.factorize(g['sub'])[0]
    # convert inputs to numpy
    a = g['num_1'].to_numpy()
    b = g.loc[~g['sub'].duplicated(), 'num_2'].to_numpy()
    c = g['num_3'].to_numpy()
    # form mask
    # (a[:, None] > b) -> num_1 > num_2
    # (sub[:, None] >= np.arange(len(b))) -> exclude previous groups
    m = (a[:, None] < b) &  (a[:, None] > c) & (sub[:, None] >= np.arange(len(b)))
    # find first True per column
    return pd.Series(np.where(m.any(0), a[m.argmax(0)], np.nan)[sub],
                     index=g.index)

df['result'] = df.groupby('main', group_keys=False).apply(find)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update my previous code to use two comparisons, you have to pay attention to use num_2 as columns. Also you need to change the output reference column to "label":

```
def find(g):
    # get sub as 0,1,2…
    sub = pd.factorize(g['sub'])[0]
    # convert inputs to numpy
    n1 = g['num_1'].to_numpy()
    n2 = g.loc[~g['sub'].duplicated(), 'num_2'].to_numpy()
    n3 = g['num_3'].to_numpy()
    # form mask
    # (n1[:, None] > n1) -> num_1 > num_2
    # (n3[:, None] > n2) -> num_3 > num_2
    # (sub[:, None] >= np.arange(len(b))) -> exclude previous groups
    m = ((n1[:, None] < n2) & (n3[:, None] > n2)
         & (sub[:, None] >= np.arange(len(n2)))
        )
    # find first True per column
    return pd.Series(np.where(m.any(0), g['label'].to_numpy()
                              [m.argmax(0)], np.nan)[sub],
                     index=g.index)

df['result'] = df.groupby('main', group_keys=False).apply(find)
```

Output:

```
   main sub  num_1  num_2  num_3 label result
0     x   c     97    100     99     a      b
1     x   c     90    100    110     b      b
2     x   c    105    100    110     c      b
3     x   d   2100    102    110     d      f
4     x   d   1000    102    110     e      f
5     x   e    101    209    222     f      f
6     x   e    110    209    222     g      f
7     x   e    222    209    222     h      f
8     x   e     90    209    222     i      f
9     y   f    100    100    150     j      k
10    y   f     99    100    101     k      k
11    y   f     90    100    200     l      k
12    y   f      2    100      5     m      k
13    y   g     92     90     95     n    NaN
14    y   g     95     90     95     o    NaN
15    y   g     93     90    100     p    NaN
```